# About an error when instantiating a Kafka node within openshift

Tags: apache-kafka, openshift-origin

i am playing with open shift in my local machine and when I try to deploy a Kafka node using this [recipe](https://github.com/keedio/openshift-kafka), but I am getting this exception:

I do not know what is happening, Kafka talked successfully to Zookeeper, I can see in this log, but after that, this exception, clearly insufficient, i mean, where Kafka is trying to write? which user is trying to write?

```
[2017-05-24 13:06:28,835] INFO Opening socket connection to server zookeeper.myproject.svc.cluster.local/172.30.106.154:2181. Will not attempt to authenticate using SASL (unknown error) (org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn)
[2017-05-24 13:06:28,839] INFO Socket connection established to zookeeper.myproject.svc.cluster.local/172.30.106.154:2181, initiating session (org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn)
[2017-05-24 13:06:28,859] INFO Session establishment complete on server zookeeper.myproject.svc.cluster.local/172.30.106.154:2181, sessionid = 0x15c39c42ce00074, negotiated timeout = 6000 (org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn)
[2017-05-24 13:06:28,862] INFO zookeeper state changed (SyncConnected) (org.I0Itec.zkclient.ZkClient)
[2017-05-24 13:06:28,957] INFO Cluster ID = E-glEZdXQvq9joWC2IsGmg (kafka.server.KafkaServer)
[2017-05-24 13:06:28,961] WARN No meta.properties file under dir /tmp/kafka-logs/meta.properties (kafka.server.BrokerMetadataCheckpoint)
[2017-05-24 13:06:29,004] INFO [ThrottledRequestReaper-Fetch], Starting  (kafka.server.ClientQuotaManager$ThrottledRequestReaper)
[2017-05-24 13:06:29,006] INFO [ThrottledRequestReaper-Produce], Starting  (kafka.server.ClientQuotaManager$ThrottledRequestReaper)
[2017-05-24 13:06:29,032] FATAL [Kafka Server 1117], Fatal error during KafkaServer startup. Prepare to shutdown (kafka.server.KafkaServer)
java.io.IOException: Permission denied
at java.io.UnixFileSystem.createFileExclusively(Native Method)
at java.io.File.createNewFile(File.java:1012)
at kafka.utils.FileLock.<init>(FileLock.scala:28)
at kafka.log.LogManager$$anonfun$lockLogDirs$1.apply(LogManager.scala:104)
at kafka.log.LogManager$$anonfun$lockLogDirs$1.apply(LogManager.scala:103)
at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:234)
at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:234)
at scala.collection.IndexedSeqOptimized$class.foreach(IndexedSeqOptimized.scala:33)
at scala.collection.mutable.WrappedArray.foreach(WrappedArray.scala:35)
at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.map(TraversableLike.scala:234)
at scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.map(Traversable.scala:104)
at kafka.log.LogManager.lockLogDirs(LogManager.scala:103)
at kafka.log.LogManager.<init>(LogManager.scala:65)
at kafka.server.KafkaServer.createLogManager(KafkaServer.scala:646)
at kafka.server.KafkaServer.startup(KafkaServer.scala:208)
at kafka.server.KafkaServerStartable.startup(KafkaServerStartable.scala:39)
at kafka.Kafka$.main(Kafka.scala:67)
at kafka.Kafka.main(Kafka.scala)
```

I am running OS X 10.12.4, open shift was installed following this [guide](https://github.com/openshift/origin/blob/master/docs/cluster_up_down.md) and after running my local open shift, I can see this output:

```
MacBook-Pro-de-Alonso:openShift-local aisidoro$ docker images
REPOSITORY                                          TAG                     IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
172.30.1.1:5000/myproject/kafka-openstack-poc       latest              06113811f186        4 hours ago         542 MB
172.30.1.1:5000/myproject/cassandra-openstack-poc   latest              d6a3bb84956b        4 hours ago         728 MB
spotify/kafka                                       latest              7ded2905de20        6 days ago          444 MB
openshift/origin-docker-builder                     v1.5.1              34e347b08dc0        7 days ago          617 MB
openshift/origin-deployer                           v1.5.1              0f23b83cad80        7 days ago          617 MB
openshift/origin-docker-registry                    v1.5.1              345b59149571        7 days ago          428 MB
openshift/origin-haproxy-router                     v1.5.1              02a2dd43884b        7 days ago          739 MB
openshift/origin                                    v1.5.1              a23dc456ea10        7 days ago          617 MB
openshift/origin-pod                                v1.5.1              aad02d5e14b9        7 days ago          1.14 MB
ejercicio3                                          latest              a1ad64693ca2        12 days ago         542 MB
jboss/base-jdk                                      8                   f8920ff5aaa7        12 days ago         421 MB
centos                                              7                   8140d0c64310        12 days ago         193 MB
java                                                openjdk-8-jre       e44d62cf8862        4 months ago        311 MB
elasticsearch                                       2.4.1               8e3cf79edcc3        6 months ago        346 MB
MacBook-Pro-de-Alonso:openShift-local aisidoro$ docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                                                                                                                        COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                                                              NAMES
89bce253d069        openshift/origin-pod:v1.5.1                                                                                                 "/pod"                   3 hours ago         Up 3 hours                                                                             k8s_POD.c39dfe94_kafka-3-8r2rf_myproject_51c884f2-4066-11e7-902e-26367c308d68_a35c5bbe
147ae4711fec        openshift/origin-pod:v1.5.1                                                                                                 "/pod"                   3 hours ago         Up 3 hours                                                                             k8s_POD.c39dfe94_kafka-1-mvndq_myproject_9b37291e-4065-11e7-902e-26367c308d68_7fc571d7
9725400152e7        172.30.1.1:5000/myproject/kafka-openstack-poc@sha256:cb4cbb6894503c5c9050b9ee15300574004db29143e22e8d2d753e1c09f90410       "bin/zookeeper-ser..."   4 hours ago         Up 4 hours                                                                             k8s_zookeeper.a006fb2a_zookeeper-1-4t1mr_myproject_90ca45c5-4062-11e7-902e-26367c308d68_12a5819c
a3cf5a956d90        openshift/origin-pod:v1.5.1                                                                                                 "/pod"                   4 hours ago         Up 4 hours                                                                             k8s_POD.b461fe8c_zookeeper-1-4t1mr_myproject_90ca45c5-4062-11e7-902e- 26367c308d68_96e8436f
a714059c8ab6        172.30.1.1:5000/myproject/cassandra-openstack-poc@sha256:f26bbb253e2cf6e0fb097d47a4a6ee45472e66fbdc90e562261bf5d18d14aafc   "/opt/apache-cassa..."   4 hours ago         Up 4 hours                                                                             k8s_cassandra-cql.6c15e0a5_cassandra-openstack-poc-1-8lpcd_myproject_eafc8ab5-4061-11e7-902e-26367c308d68_c100a39f
016962774c6a        openshift/origin-pod:v1.5.1                                                                                                 "/pod"                   4 hours ago         Up 4 hours                                                                             k8s_POD.cfb87698_cassandra-openstack-poc-1-8lpcd_myproject_eafc8ab5-4061-11e7-902e-26367c308d68_e7986c04
e2efa94aaa6f        openshift/origin-haproxy-router:v1.5.1                                                                                      "/usr/bin/openshif..."   4 hours ago         Up 4 hours                                                                             k8s_router.ccc6298a_router-1-mn6b1_default_b386f79d-405c-11e7-902e-26367c308d68_2bdaaa5b
a197561fb08d        openshift/origin-docker-registry:v1.5.1                                                                                     "/bin/sh -c 'DOCKE..."   4 hours ago         Up 4 hours                                                                             k8s_registry.10a5d462_docker-registry-1-2x9q0_default_b3590fa9-405c-11e7-902e-26367c308d68_81086abb
ec4ddd33732b        openshift/origin-pod:v1.5.1                                                                                                 "/pod"                   4 hours ago         Up 4 hours          0.0.0.0:80->80/tcp, 0.0.0.0:443->443/tcp, 0.0.0.0:1936->1936/tcp   k8s_POD.f33047a0_router-1-mn6b1_default_b386f79d-405c-11e7-902e-26367c308d68_2e28ed28
e0656a09f489        openshift/origin-pod:v1.5.1                                                                                                 "/pod"                   4 hours ago         Up 4 hours                                                                             k8s_POD.a71dfe85_docker-registry-1-2x9q0_default_b3590fa9-405c-11e7-902e-  26367c308d68_79d54bda
4368521a954b        openshift/origin:v1.5.1                                                                                                     "/usr/bin/openshif..."   4 hours ago         Up 4 hours                                                                             origin
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the content of the [`kafka.yaml`](https://github.com/keedio/openshift-kafka/blob/f816e5082f76ac7d5fbe3acfc2190b103de3796e/kafka.yaml#L63-L65) file, looks like it tries to write to the `/tmp/kafka-logs` directory.